# Retrofit 2.0.0 Beta2 OkHttpClient interceptor throwing StackOverFlowError

Tags: android, stack-overflow, retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to build an interceptor for logging in. Here is my following code for that:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request();
                String authToken = SharedPrefsManager.get(context).getAccessToken();
                request.newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken)
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();


                return intercept(chain);
            }
        });
```

My GSON:

```
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                        return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .create();
```

My Retrofit `RestAdapter`:

```
   Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Endpoints.ENDPOINT_BASE_URL+Endpoints.ENDPOINT_VERSION)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();

        apiInterface = restAdapter.create(ApiService.class);
```

However when I call this service using:

```
            try {
                    Account myAccount = ApiInterface.getKidMixClient(getActivity()).getAccountDetails().execute().body();
                    callbacks.showDashboard(myAccount.getUser());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I receive a `StackOverFlowError`, the following `Logcat` output:

```
    java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
10-08 16:42:39.013 21279-21279/com.kidmixapp.kidmixchild E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:71)
10-08 16:42:39.013 21279-21279/com.kidmixapp.kidmixchild E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Headers$Builder.<init>(Headers.java:215)
10-08 16:42:39.013 21279-21279/com.kidmixapp.kidmixchild E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Headers.newBuilder(Headers.java:121)
10-08 16:42:39.013 21279-21279/com.kidmixapp.kidmixchild E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder.<init>(Request.java:137)
10-08 16:42:39.013 21279-21279/com.kidmixapp.kidmixchild E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder.<init>(Request.java:120)
10-08 16:42:39.013 21279-21279/com.kidmixapp.kidmixchild E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Request.newBuilder(Request.java:94)
10-08 16:42:39.013 21279-21279/com.kidmixapp.kidmixchild E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.kidmixapp.commoncode.networking.ApiInterface$1.intercept(ApiInterface.java:39)
10-08 16:42:39.013 21279-21279/com.kidmixapp.kidmixchild E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.kidmixapp.commoncode.networking.ApiInterface$1.intercept(ApiInterface.java:45)
10-08 16:42:39.013 21279-21279/com.kidmixapp.kidmixchild E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.kidmixapp.commoncode.networking.ApiInterface$1.intercept(ApiInterface.java:45)
```

Comment: Are you not calling intercept again (and again, and again recursively) in your first code example? Is it supposed to be  `chain.proceed(request)`?

Comment: Ah yes, switching to proceed worked.

I will update the fix, I also need to do it off main thread. I will try that and see what happens.

Comment: ok sounds good, let me know. I've submitted an answer instead of just leaving it in a comment for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be using `chain.proceed(request)`, what you're doing is recursively calling the same `intercept` method.

Comment: That fixed the one issue so I will accept it. But do you mind if I link you in on a different problem?

Comment: Got it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33026897/retrofit-call-2-0-0-nothing-happening