# Retrofit call to server 2.0.0Beta2, nothing happening - callback never invoked

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, okhttp

I make the call like such:

```
ApiInterface.getKidMixClient(getActivity()).getAccountDetails().enqueue(LoginFragment.this);
```

Here is my `interface` definition:

```
@GET(Endpoints.GET_MY_ACCOUNT_DETAILS+"/")
Call<Account> getAccountDetails();
```

But my callback `onResponse` is never being invoked?

Is there something wrong with this set up?

```
public class ApiInterface {
private static ApiService apiInterface;

public static ApiService getKidMixClient(final Context context) {
    if (apiInterface == null) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request();
                String authToken = SharedPrefsManager.get(context).getAccessToken();
                request.newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken)
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .build();
                chain.proceed(request);
                return intercept(chain);
            }
        });

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                        return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .create();

        Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Endpoints.ENDPOINT_BASE_URL+Endpoints.ENDPOINT_VERSION)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(client)
       /*         .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                        String authToken = SharedPrefsManager.get(context).getAccessToken();
                        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken);
                        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    }
                })*/
                .build();

        apiInterface = restAdapter.create(ApiService.class);
    }

    return apiInterface;
}
```

}

this is the callback that should be getting called, but never is:

```
 @Override
public void onResponse(Response<Account> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    Log.v("Call Success", "Call was a sucess to server login!");
    Account account = response.body();
    if(account != null && account.getUser() != null){
        if(callbacks != null){
            Log.d(TAG, "start");
            callbacks.showDashboard(account.getUser());
            Log.d(TAG, "finish");
        }
    }
}
```

It is in the `LoginFragment` class, of which the initial call is being made via `enqueue`.

Comment: Can you edit your post so that the code is formatted properly? I'd do it, but  then it's mostly code (and I don't want to take the time to add content to appease SO)

Comment: Yea just did, sorry bout that. Hadn't noticed the mess up at first.

Comment: I still don't think that your code will work. You need to return `chain.proceed(request)`, instead of just calling it and then returning intercept. That's not the issue here, though, I think.

Comment: I'm also confused, I don't see where you tell it that you want onResponse as your callback. (nvm)

Comment: Ok so, changing it to return the `chain.proceed(request)` as you said makes my callback happen. But still not fully working.

Comment: Sorry, so - in my first bit of code, where it says `enqueue(LoginFragment.this)`, `LoginFragment implements Callback<Account>`;

Comment: Did you implement onFailure, as well? Anything there?

Comment: Yes, `onFailure` is not throwing anything. The callback and server are now successful. However the `onResponse` I think is returning null now, which I am thinking as to why that may be. (This all worked in Retrofit 1.9. I am just trying to make the transition.)

Comment: Apparently the `response` body is empty. Not sure why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91791/discussion-between-tukajo-and-tyler-sebastian).